# NgRx Effects: What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6, ngrx-effects

So I'm trying to dispatch different arrays of actions based on the user type that I get from the server when I make a API call to `/api/auth/login`.

```
@Effect()
  login = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.ActionTypes.TryLogin),
    map((action: AuthActions.TryLogin) => {
      return action.payload;
    }),
    switchMap(loginData => {
      return this.httpClient.post<{
        jwtToken: string;
        usertype: string;
        expiresIn: number;
        userId: string;
      }>(`${this.BACKEND_URL}/api/auth/login`, loginData);
    }),
    mergeMap(res => {
      const actions = [
        {
          type: AuthActions.ActionTypes.Login
        },
        {
          type: AuthActions.ActionTypes.SetToken,
          payload: res.jwtToken
        },
        {
          type: AuthActions.ActionTypes.SetTokenExpiry,
          payload: res.expiresIn
        }
      ];
      if (res.usertype === 'Admin') {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin-panel']);

        return [...actions, {type: AdminActions.ActionTypes.SetId, payload: res.userId}];
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/client-panel']);

        return [...actions, {type: UserActions.ActionTypes.SetId, payload: res.userId}];

      }
    })
  );
```

But I'm getting this Error:

```
Argument of type '(res: { jwtToken: string; usertype: string; expiresIn: number; userId: string; }) => ({ type: Act...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { jwtToken: string; usertype: string; expiresIn: number; userId: string; }, index: number...'.
  Type '({ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: ...' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: strin...'.
    Type '({ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: ...' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: strin...'.
      Type '({ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: ...' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | ...'.
        Types of property '[Symbol.iterator]' are incompatible.
          Type '() => IterableIterator<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload...' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string...'.
            Type 'IterableIterator<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: stri...' is not assignable to type 'Iterator<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | ...'.
              Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
                Type '{ (value?: any): IteratorResult<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes...' is not assignable to type '{ (value?: any): IteratorResult<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
                  Type 'IteratorResult<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string...' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
                    Type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: A...' is not assignable to type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: A...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
                      Type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload?: undefined; } | { type: ActionTypes; payload: string; } | { type: A...'.
                        Type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: ActionTypes; payload: string; }'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
                          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
                            Type 'ActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'ActionTypes'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
```

It works alright if I separate out Admin Login and User Login. But it would mean much of the code will be identical. Can Anybody help me out here?

Comment: Based on the error: `Type 'ActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'ActionTypes'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.`, is there more than one `ActionTypes` enum/map declared?

Comment: Yes, did think about that at first. But then I changed all my actions to have unique names and I still would get the error. But @timdeschryver 's answer works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to type is as an `Action`:

```
if (res.usertype === 'Admin') {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin-panel']);

        return [...actions, {type: AdminActions.ActionTypes.SetId, payload: res.userId} as Action];
} else {
        this.router.navigate(['/client-panel']);

        return [...actions, {type: UserActions.ActionTypes.SetId, payload: res.userId} as Action];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. it work's. It realy helped me a lot!!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could be of help!